# How to merge to two rows if two cols contain same value

Tags: excel

I want to merge excel rows comparing values of two columns: Column A and Column B.
If the values of Col A and Col B are same it should be merged with other row**s**(can be multiple rows) which has the same values in Col A and Col B.
Values in Third column should be appended with comma to the merged row.

Please refer this image to get more clarity, it is easier to explain with an example: [image]

Comment: What is your excel version? Do you have `Excel-365`?

Comment: Yeup it is  Excel-365

Comment: Then try my answer and let me know your feedback.

Answer (score 2):

As per my below screenshot try-

```
E2=UNIQUE(A2:B4)
G2=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF($A$2:$A$4&$B$2:$B$4=E2&F2,$C$2:$C$4,""))
```

[image]